# Can't access express route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am working on a mern project and I have this tiny? error:
When I try to post on a specific route, express returns 404 and can't find the route I wanted.
Everything works fine when I try to post to the index route **'/'**. Here is a snippet:

in /controllers/imageController

**ImageController**

```
exports.image_upload_post = (req,res) => {
   console.log('init file posting')
}
```

in /controllers/accidentController

**AccidentController**(works fine)

```
exports.accident_detail_post = (req,res) => {
   console.log('init form data posting')
}
```

Here are the routes:

routes/imageUpload route:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const image_upload_controller = require('../controllers/ImageUploadController')
router.post('/upload', image_upload_controller.image_upload_post)
module.exports = router
```

/routes/index route: (the working one)

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const accident_detail_controller = require('../controllers/AccidentController')
router.post('/', accident_detail_controller.accident_detail_post)
module.exports = router
```

And finally, server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
const imageUploadRouter = require('./routes/imageUpload')
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use('/upload', imageUploadRouter)
```

And my question is, why when I try to do something like this:

```
const submitData = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/upload', 'test')
}
```

in the client React app, it returns 404 error? If I try to post to **http://localhost:3001/** I get the controller's log 'init file posting'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
app.use('/upload', imageUploadRouter)
```

and in the imageUploadRouter file, you have

```
router.post('/upload', image_upload_controller.image_upload_post)
```

that means your full path will be

```
/upload/upload
```

and URL will be

```
http://localhost:3001/upload/upload
```

> **Solution**: replace the /upload by / in the imageUploadRouter

```
router.post('/', image_upload_controller.image_upload_post)
```

In this case, the URL will be

```
http://localhost:3001/upload
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that essentially your route is not `http://localhost:3001/upload` but instead `http://localhost:3001/upload/upload`. You are defining it once in 'routes/imageUpload rout' and again in 'index.js'. An easy fix for this would be to write `app.use('/api', imageUploadRouter)` in the index file. Then you can make your requests to `http://localhost:3001/api/upload`